# Using JQ to merge two JSON snippets from one file

Tags: json, jq

I've got output from a script that outputs two structurally identical JSON snippets into one file:

```
{
    "Objects": [
        {
            "Key": "somevalue",
            "VersionId": "someversion"
        }
    ],
    "Quiet": false
}
{
    "Objects": [
        {
            "Key": "someothervalue",
            "VersionId": "someotherversion"
        }
    ],
    "Quiet": false
}
```

I would like to pass this output through JQ to have one Objects[] list, concatenating all of the objects within the two lists, and outputting the same overall structure.  I can accomplish it with piping between two separate JQ commands:

```
jq '.Objects[]' inputfile | jq -s '{"Objects":., "Quiet":false}' -
```

But I'm wondering if there is a more elegant way to do so using only one invocation of JQ.

I'm currently using JQ version 1.5 but can update if needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to invoke JQ twice there. The second object can be fetched using the [`input`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#input) keyword.

```
.Objects += input.Objects
```

<sup>[Online demo](https://jqplay.org/s/IoHYN7cDpO)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

You can use `reduce`:

```
jq -s 'reduce .[] as $item ({ Quiet: false }; .Objects += $item.Objects)'
```

See it [in action](https://jqplay.org/s/jBSmueiAdd).

As @oguz-ismail suggested in a comment, the `-s` (slurp) flag can be removed by using `inputs` to get the rest of the entries after the first one:

```
jq 'reduce inputs as $item (.; .Objects += $item.Objects)'
```

See it [in action](https://jqplay.org/s/rpitQakQP0).

Both versions work with any number of entries in the input (the second version requires at least one).

Comment: @oguzismail It probably works as you suggest but then you may come with another improvement like _"do we really need to use `reduce`?"_ and this way, bit by bit, my solution morphs into your solution :-) I like your solution, it is the shortest and probably the fastest solution for the problem at hand, nothing to question about it. But this one is mine and I like it the way it is now. :-D

Comment: @oguzismail I like the shorter version you gave for the very specific use case I have, involving 2 input objects, but you're right that this solution handles cases when there are more than 2, and your suggested modification works.  I did try to figure out how to 'reduce' originally, couldn't quite get it right!  Thank you both, very helpful.